# How to fix it in Laravel while I'am getting the localhost 127.0.0.1 instead of getting clients real IP address?

Tags: laravel-5, ip-address, clientip, real-ip

I was trying to get the user IP by using:
$request->ip();
 but this return me the localhost ip 127.0.0.1
here is my code:

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $userIP= $request->ip();
        return view('contact',compact('userIP'));
    }
```

*How can I get the client or user's real IP address ?

Comment: Is this for a user connecting to your page from a different location?

Comment: This is for providing the navigation link to the admin panel only by checking the user IP.

Comment: That wasn't my question.